# CRUD doesn't create the /views/CRUD/layout.html file?

Tags: playframework, crud

I've been going over the Play framework tutorial on setting up an admin page located here:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide7

So far, everything has worked except for the part at the very bottom, where it says to modify the

```
/views/CRUD/layout.html
```

file to load a new stylesheet. Basically folder

```
/yabe/app/views/CRUD
```

was never created. I've only been able to find that file in these directories:

```
/play-1.2.3/modules/crud/app/views/CRUD
/play-1.2.3/modules/secure/app/views/Secure/layout.html
/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/jobboard/app/views/CRUD/layout.html
/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/just-test-cases/app/views/Application/fastTag_render_test_layout.html
/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/yabe/app/views/CRUD/layout.html.
```

Not all of these are the files that the tutorial is referring to, though. Some have different contents than what they should have. The one in

```
/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/yabe/app/views/CRUD/layout.html
```

seems to be the correct one, but when I try to create a new

```
/yabe/views/CRUD
```

folder I get a compilation error saying that a line in it extends `admin.html`, but there is no `admin.html` file.

Basically, rather than trying to copy every single file, I'd like to check if something was installed wrong, because I've gone over this tutorial again, and done everything it said, and it still isn't creating the right files.

Comment: PS. you can move to play-1.2.4, it's as simple as downloading the new one and changing your PATH

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the CRUD files you want to modify, as in the [documentation on customizing the crud](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide7#aCustomizingtheCommentsdatalista), though the layout one is not listed there:

```
play crud:ov --layout
```

this will get the layout.html in your app under /CRUD/layout.html

[edit]

... oh and concerning the 2nd part of your question:

The correct `layout.html` is the one coming from `/modules/crud/app/views/CRUD/layout.html`; that file is a full  file with no extend tag, so it would never complain about a missing `admin.html` (btw, notice that that is really the same folder structure that you should replicate to override, where `modules/crud` becomes your application folder).

You have taken the one from the Yabe demo tutorial, that comes from the [following page of the tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide8) where indeed an `admin.html` page is created to factor a common look between the app and the crud, and thus `layout.html` is modified to inherit from it.

Comment: you should have an acceptance from thread's owner. Newbie forgets to do this ;)